# How to get REVIT view Thumbnail with Autodesk Platform Services (Forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have found the Autodesk Platform Services (Forge) API call to get REVIT file Thumbnail: [see this link](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/thumbnails/urn-thumbnail-GET/)

But this API call only retrieves the RVT thumbnail and not the each view specific thumbnail.
Any way to get those views thumbnails as we see in ACC environment (for each 3d or 2d view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the thumbnail of a specific document you can pass the document **guid** as query parameter. It is not documented here [GET Thumbnail](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/thumbnails/urn-thumbnail-GET/) but it is working.

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/thumbnail?guid={guid}`

This feature has been added in the `forge-apis` package.