# How to get document GUID from revit model

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get a model thumbnail and I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77069555/how-to-get-revit-view-thumbnail-with-autodesk-platform-services-forge).
I can get an RVT thumbnail if I don't use the guid param, but I want to use a view thumbnail, so I need to use the guid. I'm new to Autodesk, how can I get the guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the **manifest** with this endpoint [GET Manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/). You will receive this kind of response:

```
    {
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "inprogress",
  "progress": "99% complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "A5.iam",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "99% complete",
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [
        {
          "guid": "d998268f-eeb4-da87-0db4-c5dbbc4926d0",
          "type": "geometry",
          "role": "3d",
          "name": "Scene",
          "status": "success",
          "progress": "99% complete",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "4f981e94-8241-4eaf-b08b-cd337c6b8b1f",
              "type": "resource",
              "progress": "99% complete",
              "role": "graphics",
              "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"
            },
            {
              "guid": "d718eb7e-fa8a-42f9-8b32-e323c0fbea0c",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_400x400.png",
              "resolution": [
                400.0,
                400.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            },
            {
              "guid": "34dc340b-835f-47f7-9da5-b8219aefe741",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png",
              "resolution": [
                200.0,
                200.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            },
            {
              "guid": "299c6ba6-650e-423e-bbd6-3aaff44ee104",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_100x100.png",
              "resolution": [
                100.0,
                100.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the **derivatives** array, you should find an object with "outputType":"SVF" or "SVF2" (depending how you translated your file).
Then in its **children**, you should get all your **viewable**:

- "type": "geometry"
- "role" : "2d" or "3d"

You can use the **guid** of these **viewable** to get the *view* thumbnail instead of the default one.